# How can I query an xts time range using indexes rather than string

Tags: r, xts

I can query an xts time range by using two time strings separated by "/":

```
library(xts)
set.seed(1234)
a = xts(1:10, as.POSIXlt(1366039619, tz="", origin="1970-01-01") + rnorm(10, 0, 3))
                           [,1]
2013-04-15 11:26:51.962906    4
2013-04-15 11:26:55.378802    1
2013-04-15 11:26:56.329886   10
2013-04-15 11:26:57.275780    7
2013-04-15 11:26:57.306643    9
2013-04-15 11:26:57.360104    8
2013-04-15 11:26:59.832287    2
2013-04-15 11:27:00.287374    5
2013-04-15 11:27:00.518167    6
2013-04-15 11:27:02.253323    3

> a['2013-04-15 11:26:57/2013-04-15 11:26:58']
                           [,1]
2013-04-15 11:26:57.275780    7
2013-04-15 11:26:57.306643    9
2013-04-15 11:26:57.360104    8
```

How can I run the same range query on a *different* xts object using the POSIXlt objects index(a[4]) and index(a[7])? Do I have to convert the indexes to strings or there is a faster way using integer values, like the number of secs since the epoch embedded in POSIXlt?

Comment: you can just do `a[4:7, ]`

Comment: @geektrader I used 4,7 as an example of what I want to achieve, but my input must be two POSIXlt objects. I'm trying to understand if I have to use strings (costing more time) or I can go with the indexes directly.

Comment: I think you can subset with indexes directly, no penalty there.

Comment: @geektrader How? a[index(a[4]):index(a[7])] does not work.

Comment: Don't use POSIXlt. Don't use POSIXlt.  Don't use POSIXlt

Comment: Re: your edit, `POSIXlt` is NOT seconds since the epoch

Comment: @GSee Yes, it's the same question. Couldn't find it in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISO-style character subsetting by range (i.e. a length 1 vector containing : or /) is very fast. So you should use something like this  :

```
a[paste(index(a)[4],index(a)[7],sep='::')]
                    [,1]
2013-04-15 17:26:57    7
2013-04-15 17:26:57    9
2013-04-15 17:26:57    8
2013-04-15 17:26:59    2
```

Comment: Right. So basically build a string.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid to save some time (building the string), but if it's the only solution...

Comment: @RobertKubrick it is not the only solution but it is the fastest way to subset an xts object.

Comment: I'm not worry about the subsetting, I'm worried about building query strings millions of times in my program when I already have the indexes.

Comment: @RobertKubrick if you have indxes you can do `a[4:7]`.

Comment: Again the goal is to use POSIXlt indexes, not object offsets. I have to reference the dates range in a different xts object. It sounds like the only way is to build a string in this case.

Comment: @RobertKubrick, if you're worried about performance, use POSIXct as the indexClass instead of POSIXlt

Comment: @GSee I still would have to build the string to query a different object. I'm looking to use the seconds since the epoch to query a different xts object range.

Answer (score 0):

a[1:10] would extract the first 10 rows, and you don't even have to tell it which columns you want
a[30:32] would give you the 30th through the 32 rows.